# ExecutionTimeout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.net application developed in Visual Studio 2008 with 3.5 framework. My website keeps timing out after 90 seconds when doing a particularly long task. I want to increase it to 360 seconds. Following Microsoft documentation I set executionTimeout in web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />

...

</system.web>
```

I even set debug="false" under compilation as instructed.

But it does not work-- the application still times out after 90 seconds. It doesn't work when running in design time and it does not work after deploying it to IIS.

Please Help.

Thank you.

Comment: if it is a long running db task which is running, you may encounter SQL timeout. If so, you may also need to increase the CommandTimeout property of the involved SQL command

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem. I am using Ajax and it turns out that when using Ajax it is not enough to set just executionTimeout in webconfig. AsyncPostBackTimeout in scriptmanager has to be set too, to match the value of executiontimeout. In my case that would be 360.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="360">

</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> If the time-out expires an exception is raised. You can record the related information in the Application folder of the Event Log. You do this by enabling the application health monitoring in the  configuration element.

That should give you a good start to see if you're having issues with a timeout exception, or if you have some other issue (which we can't obviously solve, since we don't have your code :)

Comment: i like this answer because it challenges me to learn how to implement health monitoring which is a good skill to have